# Read a csv file in jsx to a const array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, jsx

I am trying to read a local csv file to a const array in jsx. Here is my jsx file:

```
const thArray = ["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country", "City"];
const tdArray = [
];


module.exports = {
    thArray,
    tdArray
  };
```

my local csv file(Roster.csv) has the following data:

```
ID, Name, Salary, Country, City
1, Dakota Rice, $36,738, Niger, Oud-Turnhout
2, Minerva Hooper, $23,789, Curaçao, Sinaai-Waas
```

Is there a library that can allow me to populate tdArray with the data from csv like this:

```
const tdArray = [
  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger", "Oud-Turnhout"],
  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao", "Sinaai-Waas"]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use library **papaparse** for this purpose https://www.papaparse.com

Look this example can be hopeful for you :

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };

        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getCsvData();
    }

    fetchCsv() {
        return fetch('/data/data.csv').then(function (response) {
            let reader = response.body.getReader();
            let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

            return reader.read().then(function (result) {
                return decoder.decode(result.value);
            });
        });
    }

    getData(result) {
        this.setState({data: result.data});
    }

    async getCsvData() {
        let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();

        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            complete: this.getData
        });
    }
```